# Django saving model inline

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

I have two model's ,

**Model1**

```html
class Model1(models.Model):
  ........
```

**Model2**

```html
class Model2(models.Model):

      model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='Model1Objects',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      ......
```

**Model1.admin**

```html
class Model2Inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Model2
    form = Model2Form
    extra = 0
    max_num = 3

class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    form = Model1Form
    model = Model1
    inlines = [Model1Inline]
```

In the django permissions I created a group where they can only see what is happening in model1 and being able to edit the model2.
Whenever I try to make a change in model2, it will not let me, but if I change the permissions and allow to change the model1 it already lets change the model2 as well.

How can I do to be able to change model2 without having to allow changing model1?

Answer (score 0):

I think that to view the "edit" page where the inlines are displayed, you need permissions to change model1 as well

Comment: Is there no other way?